# How to efficiently encode JPEG to support zooming into a specific section?

Tags: zooming, jpeg

I'm using CSS animations to zoom into a specific (fixed/constant) part of a JPEG image. (Similar to the "[Ken Burns effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Burns_effect)".)

Is it possible to encode the zoomed section at higher quality, whilst leaving the rest at a lower quality? If the format supports this, what tool can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compression settings are the same for the entire image frame. There is no way to change them for specific areas.

Comment: It does seem this way, do you have a source though?